Limited outcome events. Choice of method
I´m running a study on rare events. I compare two groups A (n=50) and B (n=200) but I found fewer outcome events than expected, A (n=12), B (n=4). Can I use this data for any meaningful purpose or is the statistical uncertainty too great? I intended to make a multivariate analysis (cox reg) but this will fail with more than 1-2 variables?
Best regards,
H

The usual rule of thumb is that you need about 15 events per coefficient that you are estimating  to avoid overfitting a survival model. You have 16 events, on that basis barely enough to evaluate the group difference.
Nevertheless, there does seem to be a very large group difference that might make your situation less dire. To adjust for covariates, you could use penalized (ridge) regression for variables other than group, or propensity-score methods that evaluate the probability of group membership based on covariate values and use that information to weight cases to try to obtain effective covariate balance. However you proceed, you should evaluate the reliability of your modeling method by repeating the entire method on multiple bootstrapped samples of your data.

Thanks. Does the rule of thumb 1:15 also apply when using propensity score matching/ridge regression? How many covariates can I match?

@hklovs matching will throw away data, which you can't afford to do with a small number of events. Inverse propensity score weighting will use all the data but weight cases differentially based on how the probability of group membership changes with covariate values. Ridge regression lowers the effective number of covariates as the penalty increases. I wouldn't trust a "rule of thumb" in either approach. Use the optimism bootstrap on your entire modeling process to evaluate possible overfitting.

I am not sure this answers your question, but just for "fun", I plugged your data into a simple 2x2 contingency matrix. Fisher-exact says $p=0.000001$. Pearson $\chi^2$ says $p=0.00000001$. A's proportion is 24% CI[13,38.2], B's is 2% CI[.55, 5]). I would say, the 2 groups are significantly different?
